# Scaling dataframe with categorical features, then fit_transform() and transform() for X_train / X_test

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe df:

```
cat1 | cat2 | cat3 | year | quartal | month | y
a    | aa   | aaa  | 2020 | 3       | 9     | 12
b    | bb   | bbb  | 2019 | 2       | 9     | 28
c    | cc   | ccc  | 2018 | 1       | 8     | 13
```

Normally I would just do:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

y = df["y"]
X = df.drop["y", axis=1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

But now I have features with type "category". So I need a way to scale + fit_transform() + transform() with int/float columns scaled and.

I use LightGBM Regressor which can handle "category" columns so I don't want one-hot-encoding or dummy encoding.

How can I do this with pandas / sklearn?

Comment: apply the scaling only on the numerical columns?

Comment: Then I would need to manually add every numerical column. I have ~100.

Comment: not really ill write an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
num_cols = X.drop(categorical_feature, axis=1).columns.tolist()

X_train[num_cols] = scaler.fit_transform(X_train[num_cols])
X_test[num_cols] = scaler.transform(X_test[num_cols])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to filter only the numerical data types if you are already sure that they are of type `numeric` (`float` `int` etc...) then all you have to do is `select_dtypes` and `exclude` the stuff that you dont want.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":["a","b","c"],"b":[1,2,3],"d":[2,2,3],"g":[1,5,3]})
df.select_dtypes(exclude="object")


    b   d   g
0   1   2   1
1   2   2   5
2   3   3   3
```